# Is it possible to detect when a node module is running as a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to check if a node function/module is running as a Google Cloud Function other than setting an environment variable via the console and checking for that?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few environment variables that are set automatically. You could check if they are defined. If so, you are running in google cloud environment. [More Info](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#environment_variables_set_automatically).

#### Example

```
// Other variables FUNCTION_REGION, FUNCTION_IDENTITY, FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC, etc;
const isGoogleCloudEnv = !!process.env.GCP_PROJECT 
// ...
```

Comment: Important note: "The Node.js 10 runtime automatically sets fewer environment variables than previous runtimes supported by Cloud Functions" https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes